# sudo apt upgrade command is not working for ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

`sudo apt upgrade` command is not working for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS even after `sudo apt update` command runs successfully. I've recently installed Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an error for some extra repository that is corrupted.  If you added a ppa, you might want to try purging that suru-icon-theme repository, and then the upgrade might work.

Edit...
You could try

> sudo apt update --fix-missing
>
> That will have the update ignore the missing package.

Or you could do the following to remove the ppa and the apps.  The easiest way to remove a ppa that works for me is to use the graphical interface.  If you are using the default Unity desktop environment on Ubuntu, then search for "Software Sources".  Once Software Sources opens, click on the tab that says "Other Software" and remove the ppa's that are giving you trouble, specifically the suru-icon-theme and whatever ppa (webupd8?) you used for the java installation.  There are other methods using terminal, but they require knowing the exact url address of the ppa.  Here is a more detailed article on all the different ways to purge a ppa https://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/

Once you have purged the ppa, then you should purge the application, with terminal.  Then type in this command with the package name which you want to remove, at the end of the command and hit enter.  It will ask for your password, then it should work.

> sudo apt purge (app name goes here without the parenthesis)

for example

> sudo apt purge suru-icon-theme

that should work since the terminal was complaining about that package.  Webup8 usually works, I'm using it now for java 8, but since there is a problem with it not working, all you should need to do is...

> sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/java
>
> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt purge oracle-java8*

And if you want to clean up leftover dependency packages then you can use

> sudo apt autoremove

Comment: I had tried installing oracle Java 8, and since then this error is coming. Java wasn't installed because of some error. @ScottMackay

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)